# How do I disable certain folders from appearing in my IMAP client when using Gmail?

Tags: gmail, imap

I'm using the newest version of Gmail, as far as I know, and there used to be the option in Settings -> Labels that said "Show in IMAP" next to label/folder names. This option is no longer there, unfortunately. How do I hide specific labels/folders, e.g. All Mail, from Thunderbird, my IMAP client?

In both Firefox 17.0 and Chromium 20.0.1132.47 on Ubuntu 12.04, without an extensions, these options do not appear, so it doesn't appear to be a browser issue. In the past, I had to enable "Advanced IMAP Controls" in Settings -> Labs for the "Show in IMAP" controls to appear, but according to [this post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/R6sUno12anA), those controls "graduated" and should appear under Settings- > Labels.

What can I do to show or hide specific folders in IMAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still there. From Gmail, hit the Gear icon on the right side of the screen (underneath your user name). That will pop open a menu which has a "Settings" link.

From that page, click on the "Labels" tab.

You'll see your labels with a checkbox to "Show in IMAP" or not.

[image: gmail settings screenshot]

I'm using Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64.

Comment: As my question states, however, the option is not there: `... there used to be the option in Settings -> Labels that said "Show in IMAP" next to label/folder names. This option is no longer there, unfortunately.` Hence my question.

Comment: I took that screenshot from my own gmail account seconds before I posted... are you saying your Settings/Labels screen looks different? That's weird- can you post what yours does look like?

Comment: The settings appeared this morning on the same system, so I don't know what the problem was, but it appears to have been corrected somehow.