# Show only primary GMail folder in eM Client

Tags: gmail, email-client, gmail-imap

Is there a way to configure eM Client, so that only the primary inbox view is displayed without fiddling with the IMAP settings in GMail itself (as discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/509036/how-do-i-disable-certain-folders-from-appearing-in-my-imap-client-when-using-gma))?

Possibly show all custom views in some way, if at all doable?

At this moment I'm seeing primary, social and promotions together in the eM Client inbox, making for a confusing view.

Thanks for any insight you could provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter in Gmail:

[image]

Then you will see the label in EMClient to access only these mails .

You can repeat the process for other categories.